# Como enviar caracteres especiais pelo CMD para um arquivo?

Tags: batch, cmd

Quero enviar o caractere `>` para um arquivo via CMD mas não estou conseguindo.

O exemplo a seguir ilustra a minha dificuldade:

```
echo casa > cidade > Estado  >Arquivo.txt
```

No exemplo acima deveria escrever no arquivo a frase "*casa > cidade > Estado*", mas não estou conseguindo escrever o  caractere `>` ( só escreve *casa* no Arquivo.txt).

Tem algum comando no CMD para escrever esse tipo de caractere em um arquivo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [caractere de escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) `^`:

```
echo casa ^> cidade ^> Estado > Arquivo.txt
```

Comment: É isso mesmo  que faltava. Obrigado.